# 2d index to select elements from 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use a 2d boolean array (`ix`) to pick elements from a 1d array (`c`) to create a 2d array (`r`). The resulting 2d array is also a boolean array. Each column stands for the unique value in `c`.

Example:

```
>>> ix
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False,  False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False]])
>>> c
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 2, 4])
```

Expected result

```
          1,     2,     3,     4,     8
r = [
     [ True,  True, False, False, False], # c[ix[0][0]] == 1 and c[ix[0][1]] == 2; it doesn't matter that ix[0][5] (pointing to `2` in `c`) is False as ix[0][1] was already True which is sufficient.
     [False, False,  True,  True, False], # [3]
     [False, False, False,  True, False]  # [4] as ix[2][3] is True
    ]
```

Can this be done in a vectorised way?

Answer (score 2):

Let us try:

```
# unique values
uniques = np.unique(c)

# boolean index into each row
vals = np.tile(c,3)[ix.ravel()]

# search within the unique values
idx = np.searchsorted(uniques, vals)

# pre-populate output
out = np.full((len(ix), len(uniques)), False)

# index into the output:
out[np.repeat(np.arange(len(ix)), ix.sum(1)), idx ] = True
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]])
```